# Creating a tab in a Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

im working on a app and need help in creating 3 tabs in a fragment class.

I was following a tutorial which was suggested in a other thread and the tutorial worked perfect in a separate project:

Heres the tutorial: 
https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

But the problem is:

In the tutorial he uses

```
public class FragmentMain extends FragmentActivity {
```

But im having

```
public class FragmentCV extends Fragment {
```

Im using on my main application the "Navigation Drawer Activity" and there i can open 5 different fragments when i click on the symbols on the navigation drawer.

Now, i want to add 3 Tabs in one of those fragments.

When i use "FragmentActivity" like in the tutorial, then i get a error from the "Navigation Drawer Activity".

```
Error:(92, 82) error: incompatible types: FragmentCV cannot be converted to Fragment
```

And when i change it back to "Fragment", then the rest of the code from the tutorial doesnt work.

Heres my code:

**MainActivity.class**

(This is the class of the Navigation Drawer Activity, i paste only the code where i open the other fragmants)

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_aboutme) {
            FragmentAboutme fragmentAboutme = new FragmentAboutme();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentAboutme).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cv) {
            FragmentCV fragmentCV = new FragmentCV();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentCV).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_skills) {
            FragmentSkills fragmentSkills = new FragmentSkills();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentSkills).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_projects) {
            FragmentProjects fragmentProjects = new FragmentProjects();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentProjects).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_download) {
            FragmentDownloads fragmentDownloads = new FragmentDownloads();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentDownloads).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_website) {
            FragmentAboutme fragmentAboutme = new FragmentAboutme();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentAboutme).commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

**FragmentCV.class**

(This is the fragment which i open with MainActivity.class)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;




public class FragmentCV extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_cv);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Profile").setIndicator("Profile", null),
                FragmentCVpage1.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null),
                Fragment_CVpage2.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null),
                FragmentCVpage3.class, null);
    }
}
```

**FragmentCVPage1.java**

(This fragment shall be opened throught the FragmentCV.class)

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class FragmentCVpage1 extends Fragment {


        public FragmentCVpage1() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cvpage1, container, false);
        }

    }
```

Is there any simple solution for this error?

Comment: You are using outdated tutorial, Andoird API has been evolved a lot since than. Use oficial [latest documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dip"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="#80000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toolbar_shadow" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Create the above tab_layout.xml
2. Create the below class file called TabHolder that extends Fragment

public class TabHolder extends Fragment {

```
private static final int NUM_OF_TABS = 3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
     final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

      viewPager.setAdapter(new TabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private static class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    TabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_OF_TABS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TAB 1";
            case 1:
                return "TAB 2";
            case 2:
                return "TAB 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

3. FragmentOne, FragmentTwo and FragmentThree are your three fragments you have created(I assume you have) that you want to show under each tab
4. Make sure your Activity extends AppCompatActivity and not Activity
5. In your Activity that has a FrameLayout in its xml just load the TabHolder fragment and it will show your three fragments each in its respective tab. Load TabHolder like this

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new TabHolder).commit();`

Comment: Thanks, im gonna test it now

Comment: i created the class TabHolder and the XML file tab_layout.xml. But in the class TabHolder he doesnt recognizes the "SurveyTabsBinding", "DataBindingUtil", "viewPager", "tabLayout" and "getRoot"

Comment: Remove the <View.../> in the tab_layout.xml